# Is there any configuration to limit actuator to collect all apps metrics

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus

Background: I have a spring boot project, it's used to provide many APIs to another sectors. Totally i have 300 APIs, and i'm using actuator/prometheus endpoint to collect the applications' metrics, like `http_server_requests_seconds_count` `http_server_requests_seconds_sum` and so on.
spring boot version: 2.6.6
my issue: it cant get all apps metric in prometheus, for example:
APIs:

```
/app/test1
/app/test2
/app/test3
/app/test4
......
/app/test300
```

the metrics like:

```
http_server_requests_seconds_count{application="my_test",exception="None",method="GET",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/app/test1",} 2.0
http_server_requests_seconds_count{application="my_test",exception="None",method="GET",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/app/test2",} 2.0
http_server_requests_seconds_count{application="my_test",exception="None",method="GET",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/app/test3",} 2.0
http_server_requests_seconds_count{application="my_test",exception="None",method="GET",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/app/test4",} 2.0
......
http_server_requests_seconds_count{application="my_test",exception="None",method="GET",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/app/test179",} 2.0
http_server_requests_seconds_count{application="my_test",exception="None",method="GET",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/app/test180",} 2.0
```

it lost some apps metric, like: /app/test193 /app/test246 /app/test289 ..., it likes the actuator just can collect 180 apps metric, so i wondering if there any config to limit it. Thanks

i reproduce this issue on test env, but cant get the root cause

Comment: Have you requested all 300 of your endpoints at least once before checking metrics? I don't think spring/micrometer initialise metrics with 0 by default.

Comment: yes, i called all of them at least once before i check the metrics. How can i check the default property of the spring/micrometer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try configuring the following property `management.metrics.web.server.max-uri-tags` which default to 100

> Maximum number of unique URI tag values allowed. After the max number of tag values is reached, metrics with additional tag values are denied by filter.

In case max is reached, you should have a `Reached the maximum number of URI tags for ...` warn log message in your logs.